# white space at the bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I have is that the site keeps giving a **big white space** on the bottom of the page, any idea why is that happening?

I have this css on the content:

```
    #content{
        width: 990px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto -40px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .full-background {
        z-index: -999;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
```

and i´m using this script to fit the background image to the window:

```
    function fittobox(){
        $('.fittobox').each(function(){
            $(this).fitToBox();
        })
    }
    $(window).bind({
        'load' : fittobox,
        'resize' : fittobox
    })
```

**Update with the function**

```
    // fitToBox
    jQuery.fn.fitToBox =
    function(){
        var div = this.parent();
        var img = this;
        var imAR = img.attr("height") / img.attr("width");
        var bgAR = div.height() / div.width();
        if(imAR >= bgAR){
            img.attr("width" , div.width());
            img.attr("height" , div.width() * imAR);
        }else{
            img.attr("height" , div.height());
            img.attr("width" , div.height() / imAR);
        }
        div.css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "overflow" : "hidden"
        });
        img.css({
            "position" : "absolute",
            "left" : (div.width() - img.attr("width"))/2,
            "top" : (div.height() - img.attr("height"))/2
        });
        img.fadeIn();
    };
```

thanks!

Comment: Weird... Can we see the fitToBox() function?

Comment: yeah, I have update the question with it

Comment: It seems that your `<div class="full-background"/>` is not adjusting accordingly. If you manually set the css of full-background to a static value (e.g. height: 900px) the issue is resolved. Of course this doesn't help your issue - but at least you should look in the direction of the full-background class. What is the CSS on that element?

Comment: BTW, I was in real shock to see the picture onload ;) Opened this in my workplace with lots of ppl around!

Comment: @NielsInc I have added the css to the question. LGAP haha hope you didn´t get in trouble!

Answer (score 0):

If you remove body height:100% and make the #footer position:absolute there will be no gap.

Comment: But i´m trying to use the height: 100% and footer with relative position to make it sticky when there is a lot of content on the inner pages. Just like this http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: It work for me, removing the body height:100%; and the .full-background height:100% and min-height:100% and positions (absolute and fixed). Then make the #footer position:fixed and shows for me.

Comment: Yeah it works for the home, but when you have more content on inner pages the footer will not be on the bottom of page content... just on the bottom of the viewport

Comment: If you want it at the bottom of the page, then position:absolute, if at the bottom of the viewport then position:fixed

Answer (score 0):

Really nice picture btw :)

The problem is the position absolute applied (by jquery maybe as its not in the css?) to the full-background div. You have it set to position absolute with a position of top 0. If I disable position absolute on the full-background div the gap goes away.

Comment: Guess that's why this question has been viewed 42 times already :P

Comment: If I disable the position absolute, there is no white anymore but still the weird margin that was with the white :S

Comment: Try a clearfix on #header as its edges are bleeding all over the place. I see what you are trying to do but full-background is position absolute but its parent (body) is not set to position relative so this is causing the mess IMO.

Answer (score 0):

If all your trying to do is make a full size, scalable image for a background try using the below code. This is using the CSS3 standard and it slightly more elegant.
You can then use the JavaScript to make it fade etc. But this will basically give it a background image for your content, it wont repeat, it is centered vertically & horizontally, as well as fixed in the window. The background size **cover** will make this all scalable / responsive to the screen size.

```
#content{
background: url(img/yourbackgroundimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

I also came across a similar problem when using a DropDownList in ASPx. Using position:relative on the DropDownList within a container with a hidden overflow and max-height fixed this problem for me.

Hope this helps